# SQL Server: how to set custom default value at runtime to a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to set a custom default value to a database column in the table?

Though I set the default value and has got constraint, at runtime if the incoming value is `NULL` the default value is not being used.

Comment: A `DEFAULT` value is set when no value is passed for the column; if you pass `NULL`, then `NULL` is set. You're declaring you want the column to have the value `NULL`. `NULL` is still a value, just an unknown one.

Answer (score 0):

In order the default to work you have two options:

1. do not provide column at all during insert

   ```
   INSERT INTO t(col1, col2) VALUES (1,2); -- column with default was skipped
   ```
2. use `DEFAULT` keyword

   ```
   INSERT INTO t(col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1,2, DEFAULT);
   ```

---

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support [DEFAULT Values On Explicit NULLs](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1#nulls):

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
  id          INT,
  col1        INT DEFAULT ON NULL 2
);

INSERT INTO tab(id, col1) VALUES(1, NULL);  -- NULL is overwritten with default
SELECT * FROM tab;
-- 1 2
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0266971d720cedd1f4c462e1ab5d9c2b)**

Answer (score 0):

If the `DEFAULT` value constraint is not specified and an explicit value is not given, a value of `NULL` is assigned to the column.

```
if @value is null 
    insert into Yourtable (column_1) values (default)
else
    insert into Yourtable (column_1) values (@value)
```

You need to check the value and do the insert,
you can use trigger to do this.